# Misunderstanding the loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I have some problem with C++ loop cycle,here is my code :

```
    for (int ii = 1; ii <= 4; ii++)
    {
        if (ii==1)
        {
            ro = 4;
            ratio = 0.85;
        }
        if (ii == 2)
        {
            ro = 6;
            ratio = 0.8;
        }
        if (ii == 3)
        {
            ro = 8;
            ratio = 0.9;
        }
        if (ii == 4)
        {
            ro = 10;
            ratio = 0.5;
        }

       function(ro,ratio);

       if (ii = 1)
       {
          cir4 = cir.clone();
          k4 = k3.clone();
       }
       if (ii = 2)
       {
          cir6 = cir.clone();
          k6 = k3.clone();
       }
       if (ii=3)
       {
          cir8 = cir.clone();
          k8 = k3.clone();
       }
       if (ii = 4)
       {
          cir10 = cir.clone();
          k10 = k3.clone();
       }
  }
```

my `function(ro,ratio)` works fine which each pair of ro-ratio outside of the loop `for` and it returns different result of `Mat cir=function(ro , ratio)`  which each pair (in this case `cir4 # cir6 # cir8 # cir10` );but when i put it inside the loop it always returns the same result : `cir4 = cir6 = cir8 = cir10 = function(ro = 4 , ratio = 0.85)`

I have no idea why. Am i misunderstanding how the loop `for` works in C++ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `==` not `=` for comparison.

You've got it right in the first block of `if` statements, but not the second.

Comment: thank you sir, and what happen with the second block of `if` ? Do they just run sequentially from `cir4 = cir.clone()` to `k10 = k3.clone()` ?

Comment: Yes. `if (i = 1)` will set `i` to 1, then enter the block since the result of the assignment is non-zero. This will happen for all four blocks, making all eight assignments, and leaving `i` with the value 4 so that the loop ends immediately.